# Getting an invalid character DOMException error. I've implemented htmlentities to change special characters but no luck

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, html-entities, domexception

The character set of the CSV file I'm exporting to XML is ASCII so it should be working.

I think the function may not be implemented correctly? No errors are thrown but the original error remains unchanged.

Here's the full error followed by the code:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Invalid Character Error' in /home/paul/public_html/csv2xml.php:30 Stack trace: #0 /home/paul/public_html/csv2xml.php(30): DOMDocument->createElement('Listdate (YYYY-...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/paul/public_html/csv2xml.php on line 30

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

$inputFilename    = 'input.csv';
$outputFilename   = 'output.xml';

// Open csv to read
$inputFile  = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

// Get the headers of the file
$headers = fgetcsv($inputFile);

// Create a new dom document with pretty formatting
$doc  = new DomDocument();
$doc->formatOutput   = true;

// Add a root node to the document
$root = $doc->createElement('rows');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

// Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile)) !== FALSE)
{
 $container = $doc->createElement('row');

 foreach ($headers as $i => $header)
 {
  $child = $doc->createElement(htmlentities($header));
  $child = $container->appendChild($child);
     $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]);
     $value = $child->appendChild($value);
 }

 $root->appendChild($container);
}

echo $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: Because of the "(" character found in the element name perhaps?

Comment: can you please give the strings that cause the error. they are incomplete in the stack trace. but yeah, braces are not allowed as elements names, so that's one reason.

Comment: here's from the top of the CSV:


"Title","Listdate (YYYY-MM-DD)","Price","Price Alternative","Listing Price","Type","Acreage","Address","Address2","City","State*"



The * causes the same error if I modify out the ( and )'s.


Shouldn't htmlentities be converting the ('s and -'s and *'s?

Comment: @Paul you have to remove those chars altoghether. They must conform to XML rules for element names.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to remove the chars from the files themselves as I have no control over what input would be supplied. Isn't this the whole point of htmlentities? 

Is there any alternative to just using strreplace?

Comment: either use str_replace or a regex pattern to strip out or replace chars not conforming to the rules given in http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#elemdecls. htmlentities are not allowed for element names.

Answer (score 0):

Contingent on running PHP 5.4+, try the ENT_XML1 flag in htmlentities:

```
$child = $doc->createElement(htmlentities($header, ENT_XML1));
```

If you are stuck with an older version of PHP, I suggest grabbing any of the flavors of XML entity encoding functions found in the [php.net comments for htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't solve issues with spaces in the element names. I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Caused by an invalid element name in `DOMDocument->createElement()` - See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15248110)